# homebrew installation during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin

Tags: installation, homebrew

Failed homebrew installation with following errors

error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin

installation command used
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

I am using Macbook Pro M2

installation command used
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.